# Take part in making of something: Should there be "the" article before "making"?

Tags: articles

> Taking part in making of the Vogue video was great.
>
> Taking a part in the making of a Vogue video was great.

Should there be "the" article before "making"?

Comment: The former. And it's "the making." "Taking part in the making of the Vogue video [had been] great." Personally, I would use past perfect, but it depends on your context.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible options:

> Taking part **in the making** of the Vogue video was great.

where "the making of the Vogue video" is an event, and:

> Taking part **in making** <del>of</del> the Vogue video was great.

where "making the Vogue video" is the action of creating the video.